# C++ malloc() memory corruption(fast)

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am fairly new to programming and am having memory issues with my program.  Somewhere I am overusing memory, but can't find the source.  I don't understand why it is giving me issues with malloc allocation as i don't dynamically allocate any variables.  Thanks

```
//returns the index of the character in the string
int find(string line, int begin, int end, char character) {
    for (int i = begin; i <= end; i++) {
        if (line[i] == character) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    //return -1 if not found
    return -1;
}

//Get the characters from levelorder that align with inorder
char* getCharacters(char inOrder[], char levelOrder[], int a, int b) {
    char *newLevelOrder = new char[a];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= b; i++)
        if (find(inOrder, 0, a-1, levelOrder[i]) != -1)
            newLevelOrder[j] = levelOrder[i], j++;
    return newLevelOrder;
}

//creates a new Node given a character
Node* newNode(char character) {
    Node *node = new Node;
    node->character = character;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}

//creates the huffman tree from inorder and levelorder
Node* createInLevelTree(char inOrder[], char levelOrder[], int beginning, int end, int size) { 
    //if start index is out of range
    if (beginning > end) {
        return NULL;
    }

    //the head of the tree is the 1st item in level order's traversal
    Node *head = newNode(levelOrder[0]);

    //if there are no children we can't go farther down
    if (beginning == end) {
        return head;
    }

    //get the index of the node
    int index = find(inOrder, beginning, end, head->character);

    //get the subtree on the left
    char *leftTree  = getCharacters(inOrder, levelOrder, index, size);

    //get the subtree on the right
    char *rightTree  = getCharacters(inOrder + index + 1, levelOrder, size-index-1, size);

    //branch off to the left and right
    head->left = createInLevelTree(inOrder, leftTree, beginning, index-1, size);
    head->right = createInLevelTree(inOrder, rightTree, index+1, end, size);

    //delete
    delete [] leftTree;
    delete [] rightTree;

    return head;
 }
```

Fixed with this line.  Thanks Sam.
    Char* new level order = new char [b]

Comment: This is a typical result of unsafe programming practices. getCharacters() allocates and array of length `a`, but the following code can be put as many as `b` characters into the new array, apparently. However, a check, that `b` does not exceed `a`, is nowhere in sight. Who knows. Maybe its less, maybe its more, we'll just cross our fingers and hope we allocated enough memory.

Comment: what memory issues do you have?

Comment: "i don't dynamically allocate" is a bold statement about a program that contains both `new char[a]` and `new Node`.

Comment: `newLevelOrder[j] = levelOrder[i], j++;` - did you mean `(newLevelOrder[j] = levelOrder[i]), j++;` or `newLevelOrder[j] = (levelOrder[i], j++);` ? This sort of code is unambiguous to the compiler, but not so to humans.

Comment: I'd suggest you at least replace your character arrays with std::vector<char> and put some size assertions in, or use the at member to see no over-indexing happens. Furthermore, using operator new more than likely is implemented in terms of malloc, and operator delete in terms of free. Therefore you are allocated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

> Somewhere I am overusing memory, but can't find the source.

I'd suggest you at least replace your character arrays with `std::vector<char>` or `std::string` and put some size assertions in, or use the at member to see no over-indexing happens. Furthermore, using operator new more than likely is implemented in terms of malloc, and operator delete in terms of free. Therefore you are allocated dynamically.

Also, wiki for **RAII**. Try and employ **RAII** for dynamically allocated memory ... always. **std::vector and std::string** gives you this for free.

Also, consider the code below:

```
char* getCharacters(char inOrder[], char levelOrder[], int a, int b) {
    char *newLevelOrder = new char[a];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= b; i++)
        if (find(inOrder, 0, a-1, levelOrder[i]) != -1)
            newLevelOrder[j] = levelOrder[i], j++;
    return newLevelOrder;
}
```

Reading this, I'm not sure of the quantity of b. There is no restriction imposed at the call sight. How do I know that the for loop won't invoke indefined behavior (by overindexing). Typically a correct for loop would use "a" here, as "a" was used to create the array... If you want to code like this, use asserts liberally, as you are making assumptions about the calling code (but just use a vector....).

```
    char *newLevelOrder = new char[a];
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; (i < a) && (i <= b); i++)
    {
```

or

```
    assert (b < a);
    char *newLevelOrder = new char[a];
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; (i <= b); i++)
    {
```

I leave the task of replacing your arrays with vectors and string as an exercise for you, as well as liberally spraying asserts in for loops mentioned... That will likely solve your problems